# How do I use windres and windmc on Linux (Crosscompiling Rust)

Tags: linux, rust, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

Note: My question is NOT "how do I make this compile" or "how to fix this rust app". I am simply giving the Rust info for context, and maybe it can give someone a clue of the issue.

**I am asking**: how do I use or install the windres and windmc commands on Linux?

On Arch and Ubuntu manpages and etc. I have been able to find docs for the commands "windres" and "windmc".

I am compiling a Rust project on Linux that uses the winres package. For some reason, the compiler keeps throwing the following error:

```
extern crate winres;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

While, my other Windows crates are working (winapi, etc).

I am thinking, the incompatibility is related to windres command not being on the system. Regardless if this fixes the Rust issue or not, I should be able to solve my task with access to even just the windres command itself.

I feel like I am missing a specific package for windres that I am unable to find. The command "windres" is not found on my Ubuntu or Arch computers.
Using mingw-w64-x86-64

Comment: You need to show your `Cargo.toml` and include the full error message output, and quite possibly enough code for a [mcve].

Comment: Also note that the [crate description](https://crates.io/crates/winres) states: *"Note that using this crate on non windows platform is undefined behavior."*

Comment: Right, thanks guys. I can include my Cargo.toml. But, this is more just for context, and not particularly my question.

How do I use windres and windmc on linux? As in, the commands, that are supposed to be included with the mingw toolchain (and even states so in documentation), although the command is not found.

With, or without winres crate, I can accomplish what I need with the windres tool & command.

Comment: That's a bit of a different question. You seem to be asking for a crate that will do that (ie, something like `winres` that will work on Linux). I'm not sure it is possible, as there does not appear to have been a solution found in the discussion [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/when-cross-compiling-from-linux-to-windows-how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-the-exe-file/63117).

Comment: Sorry if I am not making myself clear. I am not asking about the rust project at all!!

I am looking for how to install the windres COMMAND on Linux. It is supposed to be part of the MinGW toolchain on Linux. I am reading online that it should be available on Linux. However, I do not have the  command on my system.

The question title and body says this. This is the question I have been asking all along.

Comment: Is your Rust issue a simple typo? "windres" instead of "winres"?

Comment: The rust issue was actually completely unrelated. I was hoping for it to provide context clues, as I thought possibly they were related.
The issue with Rust was winres was under "[dependences]" and not "[build-dependencies]"
The issue with (notice slight spelling difference) windres is that the windres command can be found under 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres' under Arch linux.

Answer (score 0):

windres package was found from command

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres --help
```

on Arch

Comment: to obtain this package however, one must use `cargo install windres` from commandline

Comment: In my case I had to tell winres the name of this executable in order to get rid of errors by adding in `build.rs: let mut res = winres::WindowsResource::new(); res.set_windres_path("/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres");` and omit the `if cfg!(target_os="windows")` check. However, I still have no icon nor metadata added to the exe. Guess the "undefined behaviour" means "does not work on linux".